# TinyMCE class name

Tags: tinymce

Is there a built in TinyMCE command to change the class name of its outer-most div? I have a div which is populated with either a PHP version of TinyMCE or the jQuery version, but the TinyMCE editor's outermost div classes are different. 
I would *preferably* like to avoid having to use jQuery.

jQuery

```
class="mce-tinymce mce-container mce-panel"
```

PHP

```
class="wp-core-ui wp-editor-wrap tmce-active"
```

I don't mind if I can only change one, although it would be nice to know how to change both. I have tried

```
tinymce.inti({
    body_class:"classname";
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [docs](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:class.tinymce.dom.DOMUtils)

```
// Add a class to an element by id in the page
tinymce.DOM.addClass('someid', 'someclass');

// Add a class to an element by id inside the editor
tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.addClass('someid', 'someclass');
```

Answer (score 0):

From doc: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/Configuration3x/Configuration3x@body_class/

Here you can also add a **body_class** option like;

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    body_class : "some_class_name"
});
```